# How to multiply 2 non-aligned Pandas series and receive the product-series with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, series, multi-index

I want to calculate produced wind energy from installed_capacity_yearly * full_load_hours_quarterly. I have

```
installed_capacity_yearly = pd.Series(
    data=[12, 15, 21],
    index=[2020, 2021, 2022])

full_load_hours_quarterly = pd.Series(
    data=[900, 700, 600, 800], 
    index=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'])
```

The full_load_hours_quarterly 'shape' shall repeat for every year in installed_capacity_yearly. The expected result should look like

```
quarterly_energy

year  quarter    volume
2020  Q1         10800
      Q2          8400
      Q3          7200
      Q4          9600
2021  Q1         13500
      Q2         10500
      Q3          9000
      Q4         12000
2022  Q1         18900
      Q2         14700
      Q3         12600
      Q4         16800
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dot`:

```
(installed_capacity_yearly.to_frame()
    .dot(full_load_hours_quarterly.to_frame().T)
    .stack()
)
```

Output:

```
2020  Q1    10800
      Q2     8400
      Q3     7200
      Q4     9600
2021  Q1    13500
      Q2    10500
      Q3     9000
      Q4    12000
2022  Q1    18900
      Q2    14700
      Q3    12600
      Q4    16800
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Clean solution and a nice use case for [pandas.DataFrame.dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) matrix multiplication. To my surprise this doesn't work with differently named serieses, but I guess one can live with that.

Comment: @Peter that can be solved by passing the same `name='dummy'` to both `to_frame()`.

Answer (score 1):

Create [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) by both index values, then use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and last multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([installed_capacity_yearly.index, 
                                  full_load_hours_quarterly.index])
s1 = installed_capacity_yearly.reindex(mux, level=0)
s2 = full_load_hours_quarterly.reindex(mux, level=1)
s = s1.mul(s2)
print (s)
2020  Q1    10800
      Q2     8400
      Q3     7200
      Q4     9600
2021  Q1    13500
      Q2    10500
      Q3     9000
      Q4    12000
2022  Q1    18900
      Q2    14700
      Q3    12600
      Q4    16800
dtype: int64
```

Comment: My thoughts also went in this direction, but I like the solution using matrix multiplication better. However, according to PEP8 one could argue "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: @Peter - What about performance? Is possible test in real data?

Comment: With 10000 loops each I got  `mul: 2.08 ms ± 333 µs per loop` vs. `dot: 1.14 ms ± 25.1 µs per loop´.